# What is the proper way of reading a text file using a fixed size buffer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, file, file-io

I am trying to go around the slow File.each_line implementation of Ruby.

```
  def parse
    @file         = File.open(@file)
    @filesize     = @file.stat.size
    @buffer_size  = 10485
    @offset       = @buffer_size
    @counter      = 0
    @line_counter = 0

    @file.seek(0, File::SEEK_END)
    while @file.tell > 0
      @file.seek(-@offset, File::SEEK_END)
      buffer = @file.read(@buffer_size)
      buffer_line = buffer.split("\n")[1]
      @counter += 1
      puts @counter
      @offset += @buffer_size
      return if @offset > @filesize
    end
  end
```

I am not sure how could I implement a buffer where I could store the remaining part of each line.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem has been discussed on the ruby-talk mailing list. The thread is called 
[*Fast* way to process large files line by line](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/225179).

Comment: I can't see it was answered there.

Comment: In http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/225227, look at the look starting with `while((buf2 = f.read @bufsize))`. It is a mini-implementation of what you are trying to achieve.
`